# Using aws-api-gateway models, how can I require an object contains AT LEAST 1 valid key

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am using API gateway's request validation. Here is my model so far:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "required" : [ "dc", "uid", "data" ],
  "properties" : {
    "dc" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "uid" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "data" : {
      "type" : "object"
    }
  },
  "title" : "MyApi"
}
```

So similar to the required function, I want to ensure that the `data` object has at least one key in a list I define `[a, b, c, whatever]`
If this is not possible, is there a way to at least prevent a null value from being sent? I tried `"nullable": false` but AWS said that was an invalid model schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `minProperties` to '1' may work. See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

Can (should) `data` be strongly typed? If so you could use composition, inheritance, and polymorphism to indicate that the `data` is a defined schemas. See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/

Comment: So `minProperties` was the answer, however there is currently a bug in cloudformation that does not respect swagger templates that include this model key. The model will be deployed sans this key. You can still manually edit the model using the webUI and add this key to the model yourself to get it working though.